# jquery mobile horizontal center without using CSS

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a div with a grid inside and I want to center it horizontally but so far I haven't found any solution to this problem yet.

I found a couple of solutions but they are all using CSS is there any other way to do this with out using css?just like when centering text you just put `text-aign:center`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

honestly? no way imo. `text-align=center;` is css by the way.

Take a look at this page and start learning css, its easy and fun!

http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningcss/a/aa012207.htm

Comment: you mean no other way than css?o well have to learn it then thank you